# sharing MACintosh?

Tags: iphone

how can i create simulator only...is it possible?i know ,distribution certifcate is needed for devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply copy the app directory from the iPhone Simulator to another instance/OS version and it should work.

So, if you want to distribute a 3.1.3 simulator app, go to

```
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/3.1.3/Applications/
```

Here you'll find all your apps installed in 3.1.3 simulator. Note that you'll have to check inside the dirs for the name of the app because the dirs don't share the name with the app. I think they're named by the GUID of the app, or something ismilar.

Now, simply copy the complete directory to the target Mac on the same location and you're good to go.

Comment: hi, i tried...it did not open...have u tried...please explain briefly,if i open that file, will it run automatically come to iphone simulator?

Comment: Ok, here's what I did step by step.
1. Go to the applications dir on the simulator.
2. Find out in which dir is the app you're trying to copy. Let's say it's 00CBFD28-C804-4788-91B6-760C3D68678E.
3. Copy this whole directory to the other Mac at the same location.
4. Restart the simulator.
The app should be there.